# encountered the symbol "end" when expecting one of the following

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle10g, oracle11g

In the below procedure i did something wrong and im not getting where i went wrong getting "encountered the symbol "end" when expecting one of the following " Please help me and explain with wat is wrong in the procedure.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE CRangeproc(in_termid IN VARCHAR2,in_cardno IN VARCHAR2,p_ResultSet OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,outcount OUT NUMBER)
AS 
BEGIN 
select count(*) into outcount from cardrangetable where PAN_LOW <= in_cardno AND  PAN_HIGH >=   in_cardno and terminal_id = in_termid;
IF outCount = 1 then
Open p_ResultSet FOR    
select ISSUERTABLEID,ACQUIRERTABLEID,PANLENGTH from cardrangetable where PAN_LOW <= in_cardno  AND  PAN_HIGH >= in_cardno and terminal_id = intermid;
CLOSE p_ResultSet;
else
end if; 
End CRangeproc;
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You need some code between else and end if. Or just remove the else:

```
begin
   select count(*)
     into outcount
     from cardrangetable
    where pan_low <= in_cardno
      and pan_high >= in_cardno
      and terminal_id = intermid;
   if outcount = 1
   then
      open p_resultset for
         select issuertableid
               ,acquirertableid
               ,panlength
           from cardrangetable
          where pan_low <= in_cardno
            and pan_high >= in_cardno
            and terminal_id = intermid;
      exit when p_resultset%notfound;
      close p_resultset;
   else
      -- You need some code here or remove the else.
   end if;
end crangeproc;
```

Comment: ok thankyou, still there are some errors like "SQL statement ignored"

Comment: i found im using intermid instead of in_termid

Answer (score 0):

PL/SQL doesn't allow empty blocks like other languages. [One way to circumvent this is to put a `NULL;` statement](http://blog.jooq.org/2015/04/13/its-the-little-things-the-plsql-null-statement-and-why-every-language-should-have-one/) where you don't have any other statement:

```
IF outcount = 1 THEN
  OPEN p_resultset FOR [...]

  CLOSE p_resultset;
ELSE
  NULL; -- The NULL statement
END IF;
```